# SQL Find An Incomplete Set of Records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

"Not possible" is a valid answer ...

Given a table of fields (Not real field names):

`DateTime, Message, User`

Given query (to return all sets):

`SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE User = 'mfamoso' ORDER BY [DateTime] DESC`

Given Data in a set (3 expected records):

```
+-------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+
|        DateTime         |                                         Message                                          |  User   |
+-------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+
| 2019-03-11 12:55:00.097 | {"V":"1.0.0","In":"Program.Main()","E":"","D":"Exporting...."}                           | mfamoso |
| 2019-03-11 12:55:00.270 | {"V":"1.0.0","In":"Program.Main()","E":"","D":"PreExportImprintHeader ran successfully"} | mfamoso |
| 2019-03-11 12:55:08.543 | {"V":"1.0.0","In":"Program.Main()","E":"","D":"CleanUp ran successfully"}                | mfamoso |
+-------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+
```

Question: Is there a way to get the following query results if part of the set is missing (record "CleanUp ran successfully" is missing), for example:

I can have multiple sets if the main query runs successfully since the main query runs as a service every 10 minutes. All sets should have 3 records.  I need a query that will return the sets that are missing all 3 records if something doesn't run.

```
+-------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+
|        DateTime         |                                         Message                                          |  User   |
+-------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+
| 2019-03-11 12:55:00.097 | {"V":"1.0.0","In":"Program.Main()","E":"","D":"Exporting...."}                           | mfamoso |
| 2019-03-11 12:55:00.270 | {"V":"1.0.0","In":"Program.Main()","E":"","D":"PreExportImprintHeader ran successfully"} | mfamoso |
+-------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+
```

I'm guessing the query would use a count to ensure 3 records, if there aren't 3 then show them - but then how to determine they are part of a set?  The process that creates the records takes approximately 10 seconds to run and is run every 10 minutes.  This may require a stored procedure.

The `DateTime` changes, `Message` does not.

Comment: This question would certainly benefit from having the data represented as text tables rather than JSON and an explanation of where the "expected" records are coming from.

Comment: Is `Message` stored as a JSON string? If so what version of SQL Server?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion:  there are 3 fields, a DateTime field containing a date and time, a Message field containing JSON, and a User field containing the user name. Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (RTM) - 10.0.1600.22 (X64)   Jul  9 2008 14:17:44   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

Comment: is there anything to distinguish one set from another without looking at time interval ?

Comment: @Borik Only the date changes. The Message is repeatable yet static.

Comment: You might want to seriously consider upgrading your version of sql server. 2008 is almost completely out of support. And on just SP1 you are way behind on service packs to boot.

Comment: Are you sure each process takes about 10 milliseconds to run? Because your example shows a range of about 10 seconds.

Comment: @alans you are correct - I am editing my post now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only 10 milliseconds per set?

Then for 1 set of a user there should be 3 with same rounded time to the nearest minute.

This query uses that idea.

```
SELECT q.[User], q.[DateTime]
 , q.Message
FROM
(
  SELECT t.[User], t.[DateTime], t.Message,
   COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY t.[User], DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, 0, DATEADD(s, 30, t.[DateTime])), 0)) AS Cnt
  FROM tbl t
  WHERE t.[User] = 'mfamoso'
) q
WHERE Cnt != 3
ORDER BY [DateTime] DESC;
```

It's just that this kind of query doesn't check if the 3 messages of 1 set are different.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like the below.  It requires the use of a temp table to add fields (an identity field, PositionInSet, and SetNum).  Basically, charindex is used to identify each of three potential record types (exporting, imprint, cleanup) and rownumber() is used group them together based on their expected position in each set (first, second, or third).  Finally, all sets with record counts <> 3 are returned.

```
create table #t (
    UniqueID int identity(1,1),
    DateTime datetime,
    Message varchar(500),
    PositionInSet int,
    SetNum int
)

insert into #t (DateTime, Message)
    select '2019-03-11 12:55:00.097', '{"V":"1.0.0","In":"Program.Main()","E":"","D":"Exporting...."}'
    union all
    select '2019-03-11 12:55:00.270', '{"V":"1.0.0","In":"Program.Main()","E":"","D":"PreExportImprintHeader ran successfully"}'
    union all
    select '2019-03-11 12:55:08.543', '{"V":"1.0.0","In":"Program.Main()","E":"","D":"CleanUp ran successfully"}'

    union all
    select '2019-03-11 12:55:00.097', '{"V":"1.0.0","In":"Program.Main()","E":"","D":"Exporting...."}'
    union all
    select '2019-03-11 12:55:00.270', '{"V":"1.0.0","In":"Program.Main()","E":"","D":"PreExportImprintHeader ran successfully"}'

    union all
    select '2019-03-11 12:55:00.097', '{"V":"1.0.0","In":"Program.Main()","E":"","D":"Exporting...."}'
    union all
    select '2019-03-11 12:55:00.270', '{"V":"1.0.0","In":"Program.Main()","E":"","D":"PreExportImprintHeader ran successfully"}'
    union all
    select '2019-03-11 12:55:08.543', '{"V":"1.0.0","In":"Program.Main()","E":"","D":"CleanUp ran successfully"}'


/***********************************/

update #t
set PositionInSet = case
    when CHARINDEX('exporting', Message) <> 0 then 1
    when CHARINDEX('imprint', Message) <> 0 then 2
    when CHARINDEX('cleanup', Message) <> 0 then 3
end


update t
set t.SetNum = t2.SetNum
from (
    select
        DateTime,
        Message,
        PositionInSet,
        row_number() over (partition by PositionInSet order by UniqueID) as SetNum,
        UniqueID
    from #t
) t2
inner join #t t on t2.UniqueID = t.UniqueID


select * from #t
inner join (
    select
        COUNT(*) as Count,
        SetNum
    from #t
    group by SetNum
    having COUNT(*) <> 3
) grp on #t.SetNum = grp.SetNum

/***********************************/
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the challenge to this situation is trying to group your sets. Since you don't have an identifier for the set, we'll have to rely on the proximity of `DateTime` within 10 minutes (or less since the process takes less than a minute or approximately 10 seconds). If you have messages within a minute of each other, we can group that. Of course, there's always a case where you can stop and start the process within a minute and it will mess up your query.

Now with that grouping in mind, you can then query those that does not come in a set of 3 messages.

**Edit**

Sorry. I forgot this is SQL Server 2008. You'll have to use self-join here.

```
;with 
t0(dt,m,u,dtt) as (
-- no lead/lag in SQL Server 2008; use self join
select a.[DateTime], a.[Message], a.[User], c.[DateTime]
from t a
outer apply (select top 1 [DateTime] from t b where b.[DateTime]<a.[DateTime] order by b.[DateTime] desc) c
), 
t1(dt,m,u,nxt) as (
-- get the indicator where the difference in time is over 60 seconds
  select dt, m, u, case when isnull(datediff(ss,dtt,dt),0)<60 then 0 else 1 end
    from t0
),
t2(dt,m,u,groupid) as (
-- make the indicator into group id
select dt,m, u, sum(nxt) over (partition by 1 order by dt) 
from t1
),
t3(groupid) as (
-- filter out sets with less than 3 messages
select groupid
from t2
group by groupid
having count(*)<3
)
select t2.*
from t2
join t3 on t2.groupid=t3.groupid
```

**Original**

For SQL Server 2012 and up:

```
;with t1(dt,m,u,nxt) as (
-- get the indicator where the difference in time is over 60 seconds
  select [DateTime], [Message], [User], case when isnull(datediff(ss,lag([DateTime]) over (order by [DateTime]),[DateTime]),0)<60 then 0 else 1 end
    from tbl
),
t2(dt,m,u,groupid) as (
-- make the indicator into group id
select dt,m, u, sum(nxt) over (partition by 1 order by dt) 
from t1
),
t3(groupid) as (
-- filter out sets with less than 3 messages
select a.groupid
from t2 a
group by a.groupid
having count(*)<3
)
select t2.*
from t2
join t3 on t2.groupid=t3.groupid
```